# How to get highlighted text from content search in sensenet

Tags: odata, sensenet

I have fired bellow query to full text search in document content. It is working as expected. I need the highlighted text also which has at least 3 to 5 words with matched text.

[image]

`https://example.com/OData.svc/workspaces/Document/abcd_gmail_com/Document_Library/?metadata=no&query=Taruna`

Thanks

Comment: btw, you don't have to put 'select=*' into your request, by default all the fields are in the response without using the select param

Comment: @AnikoLitvanyi ok got it Thanks

Comment: @AnkitkumarTandel I wrote a custom Search Portlet that does exactly this. It's far too long for a StackOverflow post, but I could put it on GitHub if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such a feature in sensenet

Comment: Are you sure about that?